# in flutter most Time I use mu mobile as emulator but there some function that need post request will never work and when I changed my phone it work?

Tags: flutter, server

for example I have sony and samsung there is some function that need post request to the server will not work on sony if I use it many time but if I change The phone it will work and Also for samsung some time he also dose not work and when I changed it will work????
is that because of the Cache of The server or some think like That ??

Answer (score 0):

Could be the time sync, depends on the post request. What's the response?